# Using sed for substitute text with content different file

Tags: sed

I would like to use sed to substitute text 1 from file 1 with the content of file 2 (one single line with a number, e.g. 100). My script is:

```
sed -e "/text1/r file2.txt" file1.txt > new.txt
```

However, instead of getting

```
ZZZZ 100
```

I obtain

```
ZZZZ text 1

100
```

What's wrong please?

Comment: What is in `file1.txt`?

Comment: $ITC

$ 28 comment> number of injections

$NOT 

$ 25 comment> temperature

$ 200 

$ 307 comment> stirrer speed

I want to substitute 28 in line 2 and 25 in line 4 with values from different files

Comment: What is your `sed --version`?

Comment: GNU sed version 3.02

Answer (score 0):

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37 says `r` will "insert a file after the line with the word"

with gnu and bash you can go like this

```
cat file2.txt | xargs -I {} sed 's/text 1/{}/' file1.txt
```

or like this

```
sed "s/text 1/$(cat file2.txt)/" file1.txt
```

Other shells and versions of sed and xargs might be able to do something similar.

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: maybe `sed 's/text 1/$(cat file2.txt)/' file1.txt` will work

Comment: what is your `xargs --version`?

Comment: it works but text 1 is being replaced by $(cat file2.txt) in the new file and not by the content of file 2

Comment: maybe double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: sorry `sed "s/text 1/$(cat file2.txt)/" file1.txt`

Comment: with single quotes I get : sed: -e expression #1, char 1: Unknown command ``

Comment: with double quotes I get what I wrote two comments before

Comment: are you sure this is bash? what do you get for echo $0

Comment: I get $0 after echo $0

Comment: indeed i don't use bash